# ExpressionEngine – Creating a submenu with relationships

Tags: templates, expressionengine, relationships

I am designing a website for a fashion label using ExpressionEngine. They have collections every season, and they do multiple 'projects' for each collection. For instance artwork, videos etc. For instance Collection A may have 3 projects attached to it, and Collection B may have 2 projects.

```
Collections
      - title (text input)
      - url_title (text input)
      - collection-year (text input)
      - season (select dropdown)
      - images (channel images)

Projects
      - title (text input)
      - url_title (text input)
      - project-collection (relationship to collection)
      - project-images (channel images)
```

Relationships seem like the best way to link a project with a collection. What I'm struggling with though is creating a submenu for the projects that are grouped by collection. For instance...

```
Collection A
- Project 1A
- Project 2A
- Project 3A

Collection B
- Project 1B
- Project 2B
```

Any ideas?

Thanks! Michael

Answer (score 0):

Answer here from Robson Sobral

> If on every project you have to choose the collection it points to, the collections turns being their child entries.
>
> On the menu, grouping by the collections, you gonna have to look for
>   each one parent:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="colletions"}
{title}
{parents field="project-collection"}
     {parents:title}   
{/parents} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

> To who is submitting the data, is quite the opposite: they can see every project
>   as a child of the collections. This is why, from a template coding
>   perspective, it can looks like a little confusing.
>
> Think this way: the channel entry which has to be submitted before is
>   always the child and the channel which has the relationship field is
>   always the parent. As the collection have to be created before the
>   projects, they're the child entries.

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31096/relationships-how-to-filter-by-parent